# pyspark query to find the difference in column value for corresponding values in another column

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am pyspark noob and trying to build a logic for the below scenario:

When the `col1` has value `12` get the `col2` value, and find the difference with the `col2` value for the next value of `col1` as value `1`.

[image: Input]

For example: for the first two rows having cycle of `12` and `1`, when `col1` is `12` then `col2` has value `11`  and when `col1` is `1` then `col2` has value `18`, difference would be `11-18` (`-7` should be added in a new data frame with the corresponding timestamp value at `col1==1`).

The dataset is a cycle of `col1` having values `12` and `1`. Sometimes either `col1` values `12` or `1` is repeated multiple times, in that case `col2` value corresponding to the last occurrence of `12` and the first occurrence `1` value should be considered.

Expected output:

[image: Output]

Can you please help me achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is some type of Gaps and Islands problem that you can solve using Window functions. First, you need to identify the "*islands*" (when `col1` changes to `12`) by using a conditional cumulative sum:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("2022-01-01T00:15:39.56", 12, 11), ("2022-01-01T00:20:37.20", 1, 18), ("2022-01-01T00:20:37.20", 12, 9),
    ("2022-01-01T00:20:37.21", 1, 6), ("2022-01-01T00:20:37.22", 12, 7), ("2022-01-01T00:21:37.21", 1, 8),
    ("2022-01-01T00:22:37.22", 1, 9), ("2022-01-01T00:22:39.22", 1, 6), ("2022-01-01T00:22:47.22", 1, 7),
    ("2022-01-01T00:23:37.25", 12, 18), ("2022-01-01T00:23:39.25", 12, 9), ("2022-01-01T00:23:39.26", 12, 7),
    ("2022-01-01T00:23:39.27", 1, 8), ], ["timestamp", "col1", "col2"]
)

w = Window.orderBy("timestamp", F.col("col1"))

df = df.withColumn(
    "group",
    F.sum(F.when(F.col("col1") == 12, 1)).over(w)
)
```

Now, using `first` function over a Window partitioned by the created column `group`, you can subtract value of first `col2` corresponding to `col1=1` from value of first `col2` corresponding to `col1=12`, like this:

```
w2 = Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy("timestamp")

result = df.withColumn(
    "diff",
    F.first(F.when(F.col("col1") == 12, F.col("col2")), True).over(w2) -
    F.first(F.when(F.col("col1") == 1, F.col("col2")), True).over(w2)
).filter("col1 = 1").groupBy("group").agg(
    F.min(F.col("timestamp")).alias("timestamp"),
    F.first("diff", True).alias("diff")
).drop("group")

result.show()

#+----------------------+----+
#|timestamp             |diff|
#+----------------------+----+
#|2022-01-01T00:20:37.20|-7  |
#|2022-01-01T00:20:37.21|3   |
#|2022-01-01T00:21:37.21|-1  |
#|2022-01-01T00:23:39.27|-1  |
#+----------------------+----+
```